# How do different kind of brackets play role in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, qsqlquery

Take these two queries:-

```
SELECT * from movies WHERE (year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000) AND (genre='comedy');
SELECT * from movies WHERE year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000 AND genre='comedy';
```

Are they always same technically, giving same output? Or does it depend on the DB that we use? Similarly, what about {} and [] ?

Comment: In this case the first AND is tied to the BETWEEN so parentheses are not needed and I can't think of any AND queries that would require parentheses. It's when using OR that parentheses are important.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, they are the same output, because there are only two expressions.  Parentheses are used to group expressions for boolean and mathematical subexpressions.  This is the same use as in mathematics and other programming languages.

When you mix `AND` and `OR` in boolean expressions, then you should use parentheses -- even if not necessary, they help readability.

The use of `{`, `}`, `[`, and `]` is specific to the database.  These are not standard parts of SQL.  They do not group expressions.  For instance, `[` and `]` is used to escape qualifiers (column and table names).  This is included in SQLite for compatibility with SQL Server.

Comment: so use of () are always same for all DB, and their use is just for grouping together expressions. Is it? Or are there any other uses of ().

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, yes they will give the same output There are technically two predicates in your where clause. Year between 1990 and 2000 is considered one predicate while the genere=comedy is considered another. When two predicates are usually involved, paranthesis may not matter.

However lets take an example of the following queries

```
select * from sometable where (somecolumn1=x or somecolumn2=y) and somecolumn3=z

select * from sometable where somecolumn1=x or (somecolumn2=y and somecolumn3=z)
```

The result will be different for the above case as they will be evaulated differently based on which condition is true or false.

Comment: thanks, you clarified well. So basically, we use () just for grouping together expressions.

Comment: yes, we can also use it for example checking for a list of values..ex: `select * from sometable where somecolumn in (1,2,3)` . This gets all rows where somecolumn is equal to 1 or 2 or 3